# Angular 2 Observable

Tags: angular

I am trying to set 2 variables from a rest data service call, which returns results in a JSON document in the elements "_embedded" and "page".

I am trying to have 2 variables in one component observe the 2 variables being set in the service.  What I am experiencing is 1 observer is defined and contains results and the other does not since it is "undefined" for some reason in the service.

The error is that _pageObservier is undefined when I try to execute this statement this._pageObserver.next(this._page);

Any insight is appreciated...

## Here is the code in the service.

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  products$: Observable<Product[]>;
  pager$: Observable<{}>;
  private _baseUrl: string;
  private _pageObserver: Observer<{}>;
  private _productObserver: Observer<Product[]>;
  private _page:{};
  private _dataStore: { products: Product[]  };

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this._baseUrl  = 'http://localhost:8000/products';
    this.products$ = new Observable(observer => this._productObserver = observer).share();
    this.pager$ = new Observable(observer => this._pageObserver = observer).share();
    this._dataStore = { products: [] };
    this._page = {};
  }

  load() {
    //this._http.get(`${this._baseUrl}/product`).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
    this._http.get(`http://localhost:8000/products`).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
      this._dataStore.products = data['_embedded'].products;
      this._productObserver.next(this._dataStore.products);
      this._page = data['page'];
      this._pageObserver.next(this._page); <=== THIS IS NOT DEFINED
    }, error => console.log('Could not load products.'));
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to initialize _pageObserver in your constructor. Edit-- what is calling pager that will cause it to initialize?

Comment: I believe it is being done in the 3rd statement in the Constructor ...

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Observables but I believe until pager$ actually observes something its not going to fire and initialize _pageObserver.

Comment: There is another class calling the service.                                     ngOnInit() {
    this.products = this.productService.products$;
    this.pager = this.productService.pager$;
    this.productService.load();
  }

Comment: Thanks for your input ... Data is being returned... I am trying to set it with the next, but cannot since the _pageObservable is not defined ...

Comment: well it looks like load() is being called before _pageObserver is set.... can you put your call to load() inside the expression where _pageObserver is set?

Answer (score 0):

```
this._page = {};

this.pager$ = new Observable(observer => {
   this._pageObserver = observer).share();
   this._pageObserver.next(this._page); 

 });
```

Comment: both observables are being referenced in  the ngOnInit method in the calling component, so cant really have a separate call to load()  method                                                                                                                                               ngOnInit() {
    this.products = this.productService.products$;
    this.pager = this.productService.pager$;
    this.productService.load();
  }

Comment: see edit... will that work?  Somehow you are going to need to wait on pager$.

Comment: Same result...in the debugger, _pageObserver is not defined or viewable but _productObserver is ...

Comment: you have to take this line out of your load method:  this._pageObserver.next(this._page); <=== THIS IS NOT DEFINED